# Extract all json key from unknown json structure

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, extract

I'm a problem with an algorithm, I want know all key(nested object, array of object) from some json (unknown structures) file in one array.

```
{
  "key": "value to array",
  "key": [{
    "key": {
     "key": "value"
     "key": ["value", "value", "value", {"key":"value"}]
    }
  }]
}
```

The structure can change.

```
Function(object) {
  var array_of_all_key = []
  return array_of_all_key
}

function allKeys(object) {
  Object.keys(object).reduce((keys, key) => {

 if(typeof object[key] == 'object') {
   allKeys(object[key])
 }

 if(tags[key founded on json]) {
   // my global var
   tags[key] = tags[key] + 1
 }

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var obj = {
  key1: 'foo',
  key2: 'bar'
};
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
//keys === ['key1', 'key2'];
```

Comment: Yes but I don't know the structures of json

Comment: @MichaelDavies, and how does that matter at all?

Comment: This isn't fully functional as it won't get nested keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Object.keys` and recursive functions.

```
function allKeys(object) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce((keys, key) => 
    keys.concat(key, 
      typeof object[key] === 'object' ? allKeys(object[key]) : []
    ), 
    []
  );
}
```

Comment: How I push to var array = []?

Comment: that's what `concat` does

Comment: Don't work I'm update the question last code

Comment: If object is a normal array?

Comment: it should work with arrays as well, but you'll get things like `0, 1, 2` etc...