# How to get Json key value for unkown json object structure

Tags: java, json

I have an array of JSON objects but its structure is unknown.i have struck
with how to get the value and based on value i need to generate code

```
    "memberjson": [{
        "company": {
            "employee": {
                "software": {
                    "employeetype": "permanent"
                },
                "type1": "401",
                "type2": "541"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "trust": {
            "people": {
                "contract": {
                    "type": "available"
                },
                "type4": "4541",
                "type5": "58771"
            }
        }
    }]

}
```

How to get the value however I can request to give the path Example

JSON path 1: company.employee.software.employeetype

JSON path 2: trust.people.contract.type^trust.people.type4^trust.people.contract.type4

Based on the path I need to get the value.

in which format I need to store path so that I can get the value easily or please suggest me is there any other way to get the value for the unknown structure

Also, I need to generate code from above JSON:

Ex:
For JSON path 1: company.employee.software.employeetype^employee.company.type1^
^employee.company.type2
"generatedkey"=company.employee.software.employeetype+employee.company.type1+employee.company.type2

Final Ans:
"generatedkey":"permanent401541"

JSON path 2: trust.people.contract.type^trust.people.type4^trust.people.contract.type4
"generatedkey"=trust.people.contract.type+trust.people.type4+trust.people.contract.type4

Final Ans:
"generatedkey":"available454158771"

I tried to iterate based on a path

Comment: if your json has a fixed structure, you can create pojo classes out of your json or use some json parsing api's to get the desired value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000115/extract-all-json-key-from-unknown-json-structure

Comment: @Ansar Ahmed   Please read my question again I have edited my question

Comment: @Derick   Please read my question again I have edited my question

Comment: Please post your code, what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a library called JSON Path https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath, here you write regular expression for the path to get the value

To test use this online tool called `json path evaluator`  https://jsonpath.com/ to verify your path

Comment: yes I am searching  solution as you suggested but i want this in java